# Understanding the concept of minimal element.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $(A,\leq)$ a partial ordered class. By definition an element $b \in A$ is saids to be minimal iif $x \geq b$;$\forall x\in A$.

But in some exercises exists more that two minimals in the relation. My doubt is:

Let $a,b\in A$ with $a \not = b$, if $a$ and $b$ are minimals, then:
$$x \geq a \land x\geq b; \forall x\in A$$
By hypothesis $a$ and $b$ are elements of A, then:
$$a\geq b \land b\geq a$$
But i suppose $a$ and $b$ minimal elements then:
$$a \not \geq b  \land b \not \geq a $$
As $a,b \in A$ by definition  of minimal $a,b$ not are minimals. (Contradiction)

How can I understand fully the definition of minimal element?

Comment: Your definition is that of a _smallest_ element. A _minimal_ element is a $b\in A$ such that for all $x \in A$ you have $x \leq b \implies x = b$; in other words, for $x\in A$ either $x$ and $b$ are incomparable, or you have $x \geq b$. A partially ordered set can have at most one smallest element, but it can have multiple minimal elements.

Comment: @DanielFischer if $a$ and $b$ are mininimals $a \not = b$, then $\forall x; x \geq b \implies x=b$ and $\forall x; x \geq a \implies x=a$ in the particular case if $ a \geq b$ that no implies $a =b$

Comment: But $b$ being minimal does **not** mean "$\forall x; \, x \geq b$". Different minimal elements are always incomparable. Let $A$ be the collection of nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, partially ordered by the subset relation. Then the minimal elements of $A$ are the singletons - there are infinitely many of them, no two singletons are comparable.